Why isn't the current in photoelectric effect graph always at saturation when the potential is greater than zero?

In the image above, even at a potential greater than zero, only after a certain point saturation current is increased. Even if a photoelectron is ejected with 0 kinetic energy, shouldn't even a minute positive potential be enough to carry the electron to the other plate. And since that would imply all the electrons which are ejected from the plate reaching the cathode reaches the anode doesn't that mean for a positive potential current should always be at saturation?

Because the photoelectron is produced within the photocathode and loses energy moving through the material before it reaches the vacuum. Sometimes it loses too much and cannot escape to the vacuum. An electric field at the material surface helps extract electrons that don't have quite enough energy to escape on their own.
